# Make scrollable table with sticky header using tailwind (react)

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to know if it is possible of creating a dynamic table in which you can add rows to it and make the body scrollable but the header sticky (but the scrollbar just needs to show in the body). I'm using react and tailwind for it but I haven't figured out how. This is the code of the table, here it is not the attempt because it was wrong:

```js
<table className=" border-collapse w-full">
          <thead className="[&>tr>th]:text-left
          [&>tr>th]:p-2 [&>tr>th]:text-[#251AC7] 
          [&>tr>th]:font-medium">
            <tr className="bg-[#f5f6f8]">
              <th style={{ width: '10%' }}>
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleHeaderCheckboxChange} />
              </th>
              <th style={{ width: '30%' }}>Áreas</th>
              <th style={{ width: '20%' }}>Depende de</th>
              <th style={{ width: '10%' }}>Colaboradores</th>
              <th style={{ width: '5%' }}></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="[&>tr>td]:p-2 [&>tr>td]:text-left 
          overflow-auto h-[330px] border border-red-700">
            {areas.map((area,i)=> {
                return <AreaRow 
                key={i}
                area={area.area}
                dependsOn={area.dependsOn}
                collaborators={area.collaborators}
                selected={selectedRows[i]}
                onRowSelect={() => toggleRowSelection(i)}
                />
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div className="table-container overflow-x-auto">
      <table className="w-full">
        <thead className="sticky top-0 bg-[#f5f6f8]">
          <tr>
            <th className="w-10">
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleHeaderCheckboxChange} />
            </th>
            <th className="w-30">Áreas</th>
            <th className="w-20">Depende de</th>
            <th className="w-10">Colaboradores</th>
            <th className="w-5"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="scrollable-body max-h-[330px] overflow-y-auto border border-red-700">
          {areas.map((area, i) => {
            return (
              <AreaRow
                key={i}
                area={area.area}
                dependsOn={area.dependsOn}
                collaborators={area.collaborators}
                selected={selectedRows[i]}
                onRowSelect={() => toggleRowSelection(i)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

In tailwind CSS there is the [sticky property](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position#sticky-positioning-elements) You can use this property to make the table head sticky at the top